# Click div to collapse table and transform its content in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are 2 tables and both of them collapse by clicking them. When I enter to the [website](https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/TSLA/financials/annual/balance-sheet) the first table (Assets) is already collapsed but not the second one (Liabilities and Equity). I can't find a solution to collapse the second table and transform it to pandas dataframe. I tried to find it by XPATH and css-selector but webdriver does not click. Because I am quite new to selenium, I saw some tutorials and stackoverflow answers to write my code.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_path = r"/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = 'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/TSLA/financials/annual/balance-sheet'
page = driver.get(url)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cr_cashflow module']/div[2]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source[0][-1])
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
df.to_excel('./tesla_balancesheet_3.xlsx', sheet_name='balance_sheet', index=True)
print(df.tail())
```

1. How can I collapse the table by clicking the div element then transform the table into dataframe?
2. Can you explain why even if I am putting selenium on sleep for 5 seconds then manually collapse the table, it can't read it from `driver.page_source`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I opened up `https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/TSLA/financials/annual/balance-sheet` using Selenium I could see, `Assets` was expanded and `Liabilities & Shareholders' Equity` was collapsed and this is the second table.

to make it expand, you would have to scroll down all the way till end, where Selenium can see it.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/TSLA/financials/annual/balance-sheet")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
#element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cr_cashflow module']/div[2]")))
#ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
time.sleep(5)
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(text(), 'Liabilities & Shareholders')]/..")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele)

time.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```